# How to center a div inside an image? (using flex but not background-img)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

As usual I am desesperately trying everything with css for hours ;) if it's not clear enough I am sorry, I try to make it as understandable as posisble.

I have a blured image and would like to put a div inside it, and center it.
the best would be to have the two elements next to each other

```
<parent/>
<child/>
```

because the parent is blured and the child isn't.
I tried this

```
<parent class="blured">
    <child class="notblured"/>
</parent>

.blured{
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    -ms-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
}

.notblured{
    -moz-filter: blur(0) !important;
    -ms-filter: blur(0) !important;
    filter: blur(0) !important;
}

child{
    margin: auto;
    width: 19em;
}
parent{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
}
```

But this doesn't work, both are blured + my image isn't really the way I want it

So I would prefer to have them next to each others and then I can just center it manually, but it's not responsive then...

```
child{
    padding: 1.5em;
    text-align:center;
    width: 19em;
    padding-top:0.5em;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 6em;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: For starters, `parent` needs to have `position: relative` in order for the child to use its position as the origin.

Comment: *I have a blured image and would like to put a div inside it* `<img />` cannot have content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer element as parent for both, and center the child with the following CSS:

```css
.blured {
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
}

.outer{
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.parent {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="parent blured">
  </div>

  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case, nesting the divs inside a parent one will make them siblings and not parent and child respectively like your code, but the important thing is that it works, so it's fine :)

Comment: OP mentioned at the start that `the best would be to have the two elements next to each other`

Comment: Exactly, but nesting both divs inside a new one make them siblings and not parent and child, as `outer` will be the parent and both inner divs are going to be siblings, it's just what I mention

Comment: Just a matter of naming I guess :)

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed this solution is just perfect in my case!

Answer (score 2):

Put the image with the filter blur on a pseudo element `:before` or `:after`, that way the filter does not affect the child elements. Needs some `z-index` too to work with this exact approach.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.parent:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/300');
  background-size: cover;
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: blur(5px);
  z-index: 1;
}
.child {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background: green;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 300px;
  z-index: 9;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent blured">
    <div class="child">CHILD</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I didn't know how :before worked, great thing i just discovered :)